# Using "more" when comparing 3 items

Tags: usage

I was reading a novel when I came across this line

> I'm pretty, smart and more than that, I love you more than anyone else.

Is the "more than that" in this sentenced used correctly? If not, would it be incorrect to replace with something like "most importantly" or any phrase with the word "most"?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are two thoughts in this sentence that are separated by a single "and" without a semi-colon. The first thought is, "I'm pretty [and] smart;" and the second thought is, "I love you more than anyone else."
Having said that, the phrase "more than that" should be an adverb clause starting the second thought. For example, "I'm pretty and smart. More than that, I love you more than anyone else."